# How to create icon inside form postlink with cakephp and twitter bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, tags, glyphicons

This gives me what I want:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(
   $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit')) . " Edit",
   array('action' => 'edit', $comment['Comment']['comment_id']),
   array('class' => 'btn btn-mini', 'escape' => false)
); ?>
```

But when I create a Form postLink I don't know how to get the remove icon in front of it..

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
   $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')) . " Delete",
   array('action' => 'delete', $comment['Comment']['comment_id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $comment['Comment']['comment_id']),
   array('class' => 'btn btn-mini', 'escape' => false)
); ?>
```

It gives me `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete`

Comment: Just a little update for your UX. You are asking to user if they want to delete a comment with a certain ID, do you believe they know what the ID of their comment is? I think it's better to ask "Are you sure you want to delete the following comment?" and then maybe add the first 50 characters or so? Or maybe include the name of the user who posted it if it is an admin action. Just a little heads up ;-)

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed better not to use the comment_id UX-wise. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot add option `escape` to `false`

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
   $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')). " Delete",
        array('action' => 'delete', $comment['Comment']['comment_id']),
        array('escape'=>false),
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $comment['Comment']['comment_id']),
   array('class' => 'btn btn-mini')
);
```

Answer (score 5):

using a button

```
                      <?php     echo $this->Form->postLink(
                '<button class="btn btn-danger">
                     <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                 </button>',
                array(
                      'action'   => 'delete', $post['Post']['id']
                      ),
                array(
                      'class'    => 'tip',
                      'escape'   => false,
                      'confirm'  => 'Are you sure ?'
                     ));
                     ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->postLink(
                    'Delete',
                    array('controller'=>'Comments',
                      'class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-remove','action' => 'delete',$comment['id']),
                    array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
 );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will create **Link Button** for deleting Items with a **Confirmation box**.

```
$this->Form->postLink( 'Delete Item',
    ['action' => 'delete', 'paramId' => $item->id ],
    ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete this Item?'), 'class'=> 'btn btn-outline-danger']
)
```