# CakePHP:2.0 : How to remove delete button name and add bootstrap icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I am trying to remove delete button name and trying to add a icon in here.I have successfully add, edit icon by this code

```
 <a href="/cakeauth/users/edit/<?php echo $user['User']['id'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
 </a>
```

Now in this delete button how can I add bootstrap icon ?

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id']),
array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id']));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add below line

```
array('esacpe',false)
```

OR

**You should try this code.**

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
   $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove')). " Delete",
        array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id']),
        array('escape'=>false),
    __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id']),
   array('class' => 'btn btn-mini')
);
```

> **Please refer below link:**

[How to create icon inside form postlink with cakephp and twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995651/how-to-create-icon-inside-form-postlink-with-cakephp-and-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

cakePHP escapes html by default. Try the following;

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__(' <i class="icon-remove-sign"></i>'), 
 array('action' => 'delete', $user['User']['id']),array('escape' => false),
 array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $user['User']['id']));
```